# Allow I.P to avoid 2 factor authentication

Tags: administration, security, sandbox, user-admin

I have a sandbox that I am trying to login from home, when I try to login, it asks me for a security code that is setup to be sent to my boss's mobile phone.

So, I have to login into the production org (from Home) as a system admin, (I know I could change this phone from here but for purpose of the question I will not do this). I have set up my home IP as a secure one, from:

Setup >> Security Control >> Network Access

I add the IP that I get when I Google "Whats my IP"

I don't understand why I keep getting to be ask for the code if this IP address is saved in my org?

Comment: Most ISPs use DHCP to assign a dynamic IP address that may change at any time. Unless you pay a premium for a static IP address, you can't really rely on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be difficult for you to use a single home IP address to add to Network Settings. Most homes are on DHCP with a dynamic IP address so it would be like hitting a moving target. But if you can narrow down the range of IP's that your ISP is likely to provide, you could maybe configure that range in your org.

Alternatively, as you state, you can change the phone number.

You could go as far as a completely new administrator user for that sandbox, with the correct phone number/email address, etc.

There is the nuclear option of setting the profile IP range to something very broad, but I would be careful of your company policy before you do that.

Comment: I think that is a good idea to modify the sandbox user details.
Thanks

Comment: One other thing I have done for this scenario is to get a static IP with AWS and then setup a simple VPN server using AWS + OpenVPN or SoftEther- that way, I always have a 'static' IP even though I am working from home

Answer (score 1):

If you establish the session via the Partner API using the security token appended to the password you don't need to add the IP as a trusted address. The session details can then be used in a cookie to log straight into the web UI. I've built this into a Windows tool that can do this if you are interested.

If you want to go thermal nuclear, you can white list every possible IP address. I **REALLY** wouldn't recommend this approach for a sandbox org. Maybe for a developer edition org with no sensitive data or code. See [Avoiding the Salesforce verification code activation](http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/04/avoiding-salesforce-verification-code.html)

Comment: Yeah...as a Salesforce employee, there was no way I was going to suggest the all-IP-address solution for a sandbox, even as a public member of a community-driven forum. Yikes! ;-) But it is good to have this answer listed for the purposes of DE orgs.

Comment: I think my use case was for a brand new unmodified DEV org that was being used for security certification by a third party. They didn't know Salesforce and I needed to provide credentials for an anonymous tester. It turned out from the Login History IP addresses that they had multiple people distributed globally test the application.

Answer (score 0):

From the way the question is worded, it sounds like you may be whitelisting your IP address in the **PROD** org.

That will not authorize that IP address for the **sandbox**, which is why you are still getting the activation code prompt in the sandbox.

To be able to get into the sandbox without activation code, you have to add your IP address to the Remote Access list **in that sandbox**.